# Does cancer cells come from same process as evolution?

Tags: evolution, dna, cancer, dna-replication

Here is how I understand it:

DNA replication is not 100% perfect and error can happen, this error can be good(evolution) or bad(cancer properties).
But its not the only source of cancer cells - DNA can be damaged by environment, and in rare cases it can receive cancer properties.

Am I correct?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. I think this is a duplicate but I could not find the other post for the moment.

Comment: Yes, you are about correct. A cancer is an evolutionary process. There are selection pressures both at the multicellular levels and at the cell level. Note that the dichotomy are associated terms `this error can be good(evolution) or bad(cancer properties)` suggests some misunderstanding about what evolution is about.

Comment: @Remi.b this is not a duplicate of that. I do seem to remember another dupe...